# Category Panel in wicket

Tags: java, panel, wicket, categories

```
* test 1.1
* test 1.2
      o test 2.1
      o test 2.2
      o test 2.3
            + test 3.1
      o test 2.4
* test 1.3
```

I need to know that how can i make a CategoriesPanel on my page base on tree model links?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [the wicket-tree project](http://code.google.com/p/wicket-tree/).

Here are some [live examples](http://wicket-tree.appspot.com/).

Comment: +1 But be warned, Wicket Tree can be a little overwhelming / complex to use. If you do not have unlimited nesting in your categories tree, I would consider using an AJAX version of your taste. For instance, for jQuery: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/.